# How to get data in fancybox

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

```
$("a#selectUser").fancybox(
        {
        'autoDimensions'    : false,
        'width'             : 680,
        'height'            : 495,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'centerOnScroll'    : true,
        'title'             : 'Select User',
        'titleShow'         : 'true',
        'titlePosition'     : 'over',
        'hideOnOverlayClick':false,
        'hideOnContentClick':false,


        'onComplete': function() {
            $("#fancybox-title").css({'top':'0px', 'bottom':'auto','margin-left':'0px','margin-top': '-25px','width': 'px'});
        }




    });
```

it will open new modal. Here i am selecting the user . now i want do that after closing modal i should able to get that data which are checked.. please help me ...

Answer (score 0):

```
'onClosed'      : function() {
    // your code, example
    var value = $('.input_checkbox:checked').val();
    // and so on
}
```